# Writing a regular expression with a sequence of words containing "or"

Tags: regex

I want to extract a sequence of words connected with with `"or"`. For example, from

```
 "there or is or a or problem with my computer"
```

I want to extract

```
"there or is or a or problem"
```

I have following regular expression

```
(("[^"]+"+|.[^\s*]+)\s+or\s+)+("[^"]+"+|.[^\s*]+)
```

but the expression is giving the following results:

```
"there or is", " a or problem or with"
```

breaking at single character. Anything wrong with the expression?

Comment: What class is this for? We just had this a day or two ago, and the suggested solution was still just as wrong for the same reasons.

Comment: we using this for our full text search logic.

Comment: i changed it to (("[^"]+"+|.?[^\s*]+)\s+or\s+)+("[^"]+"+|.?[^\s*]+) 
added ? after . and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

It what are connected are words spelled in alphabets, it can be this:

```
\w+(?:\s+or\s+\w+)*
```

this will return

```
"there or is or a or problem",  "with", "my", "computer"
```

If you really want only those that have at least one `or` in it, as in your example,

```
\w+(?:\s+or\s+\w+)+
```

will return

```
"there or is or a or problem"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the one below:

```
[\w\s]+or\s+\w+
```

Note, this will match the highlighted in the following:

**there or is or a or problem with my computer or i** am going crazy

But if you want **there or is or a or problem** , **computer or i** for the above, go with:

```
(\w+(?:\s+or\s+\w+)+)
```